# unable to pause video via jquery in mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

Below is code i am using to play and pause video, it works fine in my desktop

when we click vidoe it opens and plays in fullscreen when press again vidoe should get paused with alert messaged pause .

when i play it in my andorid browser unable to get alert message

link :http://liveweave.com/miaQVr

Js code:

```
/* Write JavaScript here */     
$(document).ready(function() {
            var v = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 
            $('#myVideo').on('click', v, function (e) {
                if (v.paused === false) {
                    v.pause();
                  alert("pause");
                } else {
                    v.webkitEnterFullscreen();
                    v.play();
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
```

html code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<video width="80%" height="auto" controls="controls" id="myVideo">
                <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it a problem with touch even handling? Maybe you should consider adding touch support to your script? Like that:

```
$('#myVideo').on('touchstart click', ...
```

You should then remember to stop propagation (remove ghost clicking) with:

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

In future you can also check if you're in mobile or not with:

```
if(e.type == "touchstart") {
    // Handle touchstart event.
} else if(e.type == "click") {
    // Handle click event.
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lhzyggqn/

You can also check if you're in mobile in this way:

```
 var clickHandler = ('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement ? "touchstart" : "click");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hcwwLrhq/

Comment: not works video still playing when backpress on android device